# How to call contents of list with streams?

Tags: java, list, javafx, microstream

I am using java fx as a gui. When the user selects a file and hits process it reads in and process a jar file, and then prints out and saves a few metrics in string format using EmbeddedStorageManager.
I am trying to call the contents of my list in a separate class when I press a button, but it keeps coming back saying the list is empty.

When I run the method directly after populating it(without pressing the button), it seems to print out the contents but when I call it after pressing the **show all button** it prints the list is empty.

I've been googling for hours but can't seem to find anything that helps.

Please see my code below,
and thanks for any help in advance.

**Database class**
This class is where the list is being called from and it contains the method to show the contents of the list.

**AppWindow**
This is the button I am using to call the show method in the database class. When this button is press it says the database is empty

```
package ie.gmit.sw;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AppWindow extends Application {
    private TextField txtFile; // A control, part of the View and a leaf node.
    //ProcessJar process = new ProcessJar();
    
    Database db = new Database();
    //QueryDB qdb = new QueryDB();
    ProcessJar pj = new ProcessJar();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setTitle("");
        stage.setWidth(800);
        stage.setHeight(400);

        
        stage.setOnCloseRequest((e) -> System.exit(0));

        
        VBox box = new VBox();
        box.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        box.setSpacing(8);

        // **Strategy Pattern**. Configure the Context with a Concrete Strategy
        Scene scene = new Scene(box);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar(); // A ToolBar is a composite node for Buttons (leaf nodes)

        Button btnQuit = new Button("Quit"); // A Leaf node
        btnQuit.setOnAction(e -> System.exit(0)); // Plant an observer on the button
        toolBar.getItems().add(btnQuit); // Add to the parent node and build the tree

        Button btnAdd = new Button("Show all"); // A Leaf node
        btnAdd.setOnAction(e -> {
            db.show(); <<<<<<-----When this button is pressed its supposed to show the contents of the database, but its coming back empty
        });
        toolBar.getItems().add(btnAdd); // Add to the parent node and build the tree

        Button btnDelete = new Button("Delete"); // A Leaf node
        btnDelete.setOnAction(e -> {
            db.emptyDb();

        });
        toolBar.getItems().add(btnDelete); // Add to the parent node and build the tree

        /*
         * Add all the sub trees of nodes to the parent node and build the tree
         */
        box.getChildren().add(getFileChooserPane(stage)); // Add the sub tree to the main tree
        box.getChildren().add(toolBar); // Add the sub tree to the main tree

        // Display the window
        stage.show();
        stage.centerOnScreen();
    }

    /*
     * This method builds a TitledPane containing the controls for the file chooser
     * part of the application. We could have created a specialised instance of the
     * class TitledPane using inheritance and moved all of the method into its own
     * class (OCP).
     */
    private TitledPane getFileChooserPane(Stage stage) {
        VBox panel = new VBox(); // ** A concrete strategy ***

        txtFile = new TextField(); // A leaf node

        FileChooser fc = new FileChooser(); // A leaf node
        fc.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("JAR Files", "*.jar"));

        Button btnOpen = new Button("Select File"); // A leaf node
        btnOpen.setOnAction(e -> { // Plant an observer on the button
            File f = fc.showOpenDialog(stage);
            // convert f to string
            txtFile.setText(f.getAbsolutePath());
        });

        Button btnProcess = new Button("Process"); // A leaf node
        btnProcess.setOnAction(e -> { // Plant an observer on the button
            File f = new File(txtFile.getText());
            System.out.println("[INFO] Processing file " + f.getName());

            try {
                pj.process(f.toString());
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        });

        ToolBar tb = new ToolBar(); // A composite node
        tb.getItems().add(btnOpen); // Add to the parent node and build a sub tree
        tb.getItems().add(btnProcess); // Add to the parent node and build a sub tree

        panel.getChildren().add(txtFile); // Add to the parent node and build a sub tree
        panel.getChildren().add(tb); // Add to the parent node and build a sub tree

        TitledPane tp = new TitledPane("Select File to Process", panel); // Add to the parent node and build a sub tree
        tp.setCollapsible(false);
        return tp;
    }


}
```

**Runner**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;

public class Runner {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("[INFO] Launching GUI...");
        Application.launch(AppWindow.class, args);

        
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the problem, exactly? and how is it related to javafx?

Comment: When I click the "Show all" button it doesn't get the contents of the database. It's saying it's empty. Ive been doing a few test and data seems to be going in.

Comment: then why do you show all of the - as you say working - db code but nothing of the not-working ui code ;) [mcve] please

Comment: Button btnAdd = new Button("Show all"); // A Leaf node
        btnAdd.setOnAction(e -> {
            db.show();
        });

Comment: That is the UI code? It's a button and when you press it, it calls a function??

Comment: Just put in my whole java fx class, if that helps

Comment: why do you insist on a unrelated tag (microstream)?

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be with missing call to `Database :: addElement` in `AppWindow` class.

The method to add something to the database is called only inside `ProcessJar` class twice, and it is using its own instance of `Database`.

You should add another button in `AppWindow` and set its action to `db.addElement("something");`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will try that now.